# How to determine if Cassini is what's running your web app?

Tags: .net, cassini

Basically, the question in the title - how can I / is it possible to determine that Cassini is what's running my app versus IIS? Basically I want my code to know that it's debugging, so if I'm missing something easier here, please point it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I like a lot of the ideas here, I think I found a simple way to accomplish this.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached
```

[This gives a boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) depending on whether there's a debugger attached to the executing code.

I still like the `#if` code provided by vc 74, but this code serves my purpose better.

Comment: This is good if you're always debugging.  But you "can start without" debugging and run your app in casini without debugging.

Comment: Even when being run under IIS, it can be in debug mode, no ?

Comment: correct. While this solution doesn't tell me if Casini is what's running the app, the end goal of having my code know that it's debugging is realized. Granted, not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .Any(
        a => a.FullName.StartsWith("WebDev.WebHost")
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the port.  Casini always runs on a random high port.  IIS will usually be 80 or 443 unless you've configured it differently.

Comment: True, but not always a valid test -> what if the application is running behind a load balancer that sends the traffic on a different port -- a higher port (a situation I've come across).

Comment: Microsoft's Cassini does not accept remote connections, so if you received a remote response, it should be from IIS. HTTP server header should tell you the truth usually.

Comment: What's the API for getting the server port in MVC?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is solely to determine whether you are debugging (in which case the build configuration will probably be debug), you can use something like:

```
#if DEBUG
    // Code compiled only if debug configuration selected (not release)
#endif
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The following suggest that your app is running under casini:

- When you run your app, if your URL in
  the browser has a port mentioned in
  it (generally a high number - greater than 1000)
- You can check your project properties (Web tab) to check if it is running under IIS or Web Development server (casini)
- There will be a
  process running for casini server
  WebServer40.exe

Comment: So far I think I like the idea of checking running processes the best, though wouldn't that potentially open a security hole?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want to determine if you are in debug mode or not and perhaps apply some debugging logic?

In the past, I have accomplished what you are attempting to achieve using a key that I added in the web.config.  When I am developing and debugging, I set the variable RunningFromVisualStudio=true and when I promote to production, I set it the variable to false.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze the HTTP response and see what is the Server field. That should tell the truth. IIS will tell it is IIS (with version number) by default.